# Is non-breaking space always treated like whitespace in Javascript source?

Tags: javascript

While doing a code review of some Javascript files, my code review tool was showing "�" (missing character symbol) in one of the files. Upon further investigation, it turned out that the developer had used non-breaking spaces in their code. (Probably a result of copy/pasting from web.)

To my surprise, this works fine in Chrome, IE11, and Edge. But I'm concerned that it wouldn't work in all browsers. Is this a required feature of Javascript language that I can rely on? Or is this something I need to tell the developer to fix to avoid potential issues on other browsers?

Here is an example:

```js
//NOTE: All spaces in below code are non-breaking space (0xA0), not space (0x20)
function test() {
  var mystr = 'hello';
  alert(mystr);
}

test();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, no-break spaces are considered whitespace according to the ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification:

[White Space Code Points](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space):

> ```
> Code Point:   Name:                                   Abbreviation:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> U+0009        CHARACTER TABULATION                    <TAB>
> U+000B        LINE TABULATION                         <VT>
> U+000C        FORM FEED (FF)                          <FF>
> U+0020        SPACE                                   <SP>
> U+00A0        NO-BREAK SPACE                          <NBSP>
> U+FEFF        ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE               <ZWNBSP>
> Other (Zs)    Any other unicode "Separator, space"    <USP>
> ```

*Zs* refers to code points listed in the ["Separator, space" (Zs) category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) by Unicode 5.1. ECMAScript.

Example code featuring all kinds of whitespace:

```js
// var keyword followed by different kinds of whitespace:
var tab = " ";
varvt = "";
varff = "";
var sp = " ";
var nbsp = " ";
varzwnbsp = "";
var usp = " ";

console.log("whitespace:", tab, vt, ff, sp, nbsp, zwnbsp, usp);
```

> ... is this something I need to tell the developer to fix to avoid
>   potential issues on other browsers?

I recommend using spaces only (some allow tabs) as it prevents all kinds of whitespace mangling by different text editors and readability issues as demonstrated by above code sample.

Comment: Ugh, the stackoverflow editor mangles whitespace, too. So the above snippet doesn't execute. I'll report this on meta...